# what are some synonyms for alcohol tolerance?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, slang

I've searched for some slangy synonyms of alcohol tolerance but couldn't really find any. For example: he has high (synonym of alcohol tolerance).

Comment: Someone with great tolerance is said to have a hollow leg.

Answer (score 2):

One idiomatic expression is: ***[Hold one’s liquor](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+one%E2%80%99s+liquor)***

> To be able to consume alcohol without becoming noticeably intoxicated or exhibiting other negative effects, such as becoming ill or unconscious. To have a high tolerance for alcohol.
>
> - I'm sorry for acting like such a fool at the party—I don't even remember what happened. I guess I just can't hold my liquor.

(The Free Dictiinary)

Also:

***[drink someone under the table :](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/drink-someone-under-the-table)***

> to drink more alcohol than someone else without becoming as drunk as they do.
>
> - She could drink all the men under the table.

(MacMillan Dictionary)

Comment: Thank you for you help. I kinda know those 2 expressions and I'm wondering if there's any shorter words for alcohol tolerance without implication that it's high or low